# Run user command as Root from systemd?

Tags: linux, command-line, python

I'm trying to execute command which contains `yt` installed by pip which is called by python script thru systemd.

Python script contains

`subprocess.Popen(["yt", "playurl", "https://www.youtube..."])`
So when I call this command as user, or by using `python script.py` it works. But as Root user it shows my that `yt` doesn't exists.
I tried to use `runuser -u` doesn't work

*UPDATE* got it by installing package as root with pip.
But i think its not good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that the yt command is/was only in your users PATH and not available in root's PATH. So your solution of installing the package with root is the *only* solution. The other option, which imo would actually be not a good way of doing it, is to give the binary path of the users (probably in `~/.local/bin/yt`) in the subprocess.Popen, and that is somewhat of a backbender to just use that programm as root.